# Победа над кем-то или кого-то?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Меня царапнуло выражение "победа над фашизмом". Правильно ли так говорить или нужно сформулировать предложение как-то иначе?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: 
А) победить фашизм, поразить противника, 
Б) победа над фашизмом, поражение фашизма.

Интересно,  что предложения с глаголами «победить и поразить» строятся по одинаковой схеме: Субъект (И.п.)  победил/поразил  объект (В.п.). Предложение симметричное: субъект и объект можно поменять местами в обоих случаях.

Казалось бы, какая между ними разница? Задача решается довольно просто, если заглянуть в толковый словарь. Победа –  это успех победителя и поражение его противника: победа (кого над кем/чем), победа субъекта над объектом.   Поражение – это только неудача побежденного.

Таким образом,  двойное отношение  (как к субъекту, так и  к объекту)  имеет только слово «победа», и эти значения передают разные падежные формы: победа народа, победа над врагом.  А слово «поражение» имеет одно значение и одну форму: поражение противника.

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно выстроили семантический ряд. Поразить фашизм - поражение фашизма. Но победить фашизм - победа кого-то над фашизмом. Здесь предполагаются 2 действующих лица, и одно побеждает другое. Чья победа, тот и победитель. Победа фашизма - это очень плохо.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, "победить фашизм", но "победа над фашизмом"